# NullPointerException using execSQL(cmd) method with Android

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock, android-context

For a while now I keep getting an error with an Android app I'm writing. (I'm new to Android and relatively to Java.) I can't figure out when I'm getting this error when I feel like I've covered all my bases with creating a simple table and adding data to it. For every other table in my app, I have no trouble. However, my "settings" database keeps giving me trouble. (Using Android's Preferences classes aren't an option.)

Here is the **stack trace** from my testing AVD which uses Google APIs 8.

```
01-19 16:51:43.848: W/ActivityThread(388): Application com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-19 16:51:43.897: I/System.out(388): Sending WAIT chunk
01-19 16:51:44.107: I/dalvikvm(388): Debugger is active
01-19 16:51:44.107: I/System.out(388): Debugger has connected
01-19 16:51:44.107: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:44.307: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:44.507: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:44.738: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:44.937: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:45.137: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:45.337: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:45.537: I/System.out(388): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-19 16:51:45.737: I/System.out(388): debugger has settled (1321)
01-19 16:51:46.867: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
01-19 16:51:46.867: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5075: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-19 16:51:46.867: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-19 16:51:46.878: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-19 16:51:46.897: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
01-19 16:51:46.897: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3801: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
01-19 16:51:46.897: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getTranslationY
01-19 16:51:46.897: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3802: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
01-19 16:51:46.897: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setAlpha
01-19 16:51:46.897: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3805: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
01-19 16:51:46.897: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setTranslationY
01-19 16:51:46.897: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3813: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-19 16:51:46.897: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-19 16:51:46.907: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-19 16:51:46.947: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
01-19 16:51:46.947: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 326: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-19 16:51:46.947: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01d1
01-19 16:51:46.947: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
01-19 16:51:46.947: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 322: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-19 16:51:46.947: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01df
01-19 16:51:46.947: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x01d4-01d8 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
01-19 16:51:46.957: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x01e2-01e8 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
01-19 16:51:47.047: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getAlpha
01-19 16:51:47.047: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3546: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
01-19 16:51:47.047: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-19 16:51:47.047: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
01-19 16:51:47.047: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationX
01-19 16:51:47.047: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3556: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
01-19 16:51:47.047: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
01-19 16:51:47.057: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationY
01-19 16:51:47.057: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3557: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
01-19 16:51:47.057: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setAlpha
01-19 16:51:47.057: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3572: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.057: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationX
01-19 16:51:47.057: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3576: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-19 16:51:47.057: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.067: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationY
01-19 16:51:47.067: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3577: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.067: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
01-19 16:51:47.067: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
01-19 16:51:47.127: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.dispatchHoverEvent
01-19 16:51:47.127: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5936: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-19 16:51:47.127: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
01-19 16:51:47.127: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
01-19 16:51:47.137: I/dalvikvm(388): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
01-19 16:51:47.137: W/dalvikvm(388): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3804: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
01-19 16:51:47.137: D/dalvikvm(388): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
01-19 16:51:47.537: D/AndroidRuntime(388): Shutting down VM
01-19 16:51:47.537: W/dalvikvm(388): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife/com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.database.dbAdapter.doOnFirstRun(dbAdapter.java:118)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.database.dbAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(dbAdapter.java:139)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.database.dbAdapter.open(dbAdapter.java:38)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-19 16:51:47.597: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  ... 11 more
```

From what I understand, the ABS stuff in the log has nothing to do with the actual problem.

**MainActivity.class**

```
    package com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.ui.PagerAdapter;
import com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.Updater;
import com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.UpdaterTask;
import com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.database.dbAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    // The context used for the Updater class
    public static Context context;

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    /*
     * I'm not entirely sure what this does, but it's key in implementing the
     * tab/swiping navigation. See documentation here:
     * http://developer.android.com
     * /reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
     */
    ViewPager viewPager;

    // The AsyncTask class Updater
    public static Updater updater;

    private static ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        // Perform initial update
        dbAdapter dba = new dbAdapter(this);
        dba.open();

        String doesDBexist = dba.getSetting("firstRun");

        if(doesDBexist == null) {
            dba.doOnFirstRun();
        }

        if (dba.getSetting("firstRun").equals("true")) {

            /*
             * Checks if network connection is available and if so, starts the
             * updater
             */
            NetworkInfo ni = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (ni != null) {
                // Updates if there is a connection
                new UpdaterTask().execute();
                pd = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)
                        .show(this, "@string/progress_dialog_updating_title",
                                "@string/progress_dialog_updating_body");
                dba.addSetting("firstRun", "false");
            } else {
                // Tells user there's no connection and closes activity
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("@string/no_internet_dialog_title")
                        .setMessage("@string/no_internet_dialog_body")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
            }
        }

        dba.close();

        // Sets up tabs
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // The method is called when a tab is clicked or the user swipes.
        viewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // Creates "Life" tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Life")
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Called when a tab is selected.
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**dbAdapter.class**

```
package com.lakesidebaptist.lakesidelife.update.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * The database adapter for the application database.
 * 
 * @author andrew
 */
public class dbAdapter {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lakeside";
    /**
     * This should be changed whenever the format of the application database
     * changes in such a way that the onUpgrade() method must be called.
     */
    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private final Context context;

    public dbAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Opens the database.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public dbAdapter open() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sumbits query to database. Note this function does NOT return anything.
     * You must use the read() function to read from the database.
     * 
     * @param command
     */
    public void query(String command) {
        db.execSQL(command);
    }

    /**
     * This function should be used to read from a database. Notice "table" is
     * the only required parameter.
                + setting + "', '" + value + "');";
        query(command);
    }

    public void changeSetting(String setting, String value) {
        String command = "UPDATE 'settings' SET 'value'='" + value + "' WHERE '" + setting + "'='" + value + "';";
        query(command);
    }

    public String getSetting(String setting) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT 'value' FROM 'settings' WHERE 'setting'='" + setting
                        + "';", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
    }

    public void doOnFirstRun() {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'settings' ('setting' text, 'value' text);");
        addSetting("firstRun", "true");
        addSetting("updateServiceTimout", "60");
        addSetting("updateTimeUnit", "minute");
    }

    /**
     * I don't normally use nested classes due to my OCD, but I caved with this,
     * because all the online examples did it, and I didn't have time to figure
     * out how to make this class in its own file.
     * 
     * @author andrew
     * 
     */
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            doOnFirstRun();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize `db` (i.e it still refers to `null`), that's why a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: I posted the wrong code. db _should_ have been initialized when I crated the dbAdapter object dba in MainActivity.class. (Please note the edit to my original post.) I called dba.open(), which should have initialized db. Is that right?

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, I replaced the SQLite query "SELECT 'value' FROM 'settings' WHERE 'setting'='whatever'" with 'SELECT * FROM 'settings'". This got it to work, but any advice on what could have been happening under the hood would be great.